# Microsoft Azure UI name?

Tags: azure, webui

Have you had a chance to work with Microsoft Windows Azure web UI ? specially the new one.
[image]

Is that a specific UI web platform that we can develop applications using that or it is specially created for microsoft internal use only ?

If its available for development It would be much appreciated to have some information about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not publicly available, but you can vote for [this feedback idea](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-preview-portal/suggestions/5048221-open-source-the-portal-blade-tech) to open source the portal framework.

Comment: Mmmmm, Interesting ! Thanks.